# Why does State's build() method keep get called even if Widget is not visible?

Tags: flutter

This example Flutter app consist of  a Drawer and two "pages" (Scaffolds) that can be navigated using the drawer:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyTestDrawer extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyTestDrawerState createState() => new _MyTestDrawerState();
}

class _MyTestDrawerState extends State<MyTestDrawer> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return new Drawer(child: new ListView(
        children: <Widget>[

          new ListTile(
              leading: new Icon(Icons.pregnant_woman),
              title: new Text('Homepage'),
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/');
              }
          ),
          new ListTile(
              leading: new Icon(Icons.group),
              title: new Text('Second page'),
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/second');
              }
          ),
          new AboutListTile(
              icon: new Icon(Icons.help)
          )
        ]
    )
    );

  }
}

final MyTestDrawer _drawer = new MyTestDrawer();


class FlutterTestApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return new MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Test',
        theme: new ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: new HomepageWidget(),
        routes: <String, WidgetBuilder> {
          '/second': (BuildContext context) => new SecondPage(),
        }
    );


  }
}


class HomepageWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomepageWidgetState createState() => new _HomepageWidgetState();
}

class _HomepageWidgetState extends State<HomepageWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('build: ' + this.toString());

    return new Scaffold(
      drawer: _drawer,
      appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text('Homepage')),
      body: new Container(
          child: new Center(child: new Text('Homepage'))
      )
    );
  }
}


class SecondPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SecondPageState createState() => new _SecondPageState();
}

class _SecondPageState extends State<SecondPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    print('build: '+ this.toString());

    return new Scaffold(
        drawer: _drawer,
        appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text('Second page')),
        body: new Container(
            child: new Center(child: new Text('Second page'))
        )
    );
  }
}



void main() {
  runApp(new FlutterTestApp());
}
```

I have a `print` debug statement in both the HomepageState and SecondPageState build() methods.

When I run this app and navigate between the *Homepage* and the *Second page* I eventually get this in my log:

```
build: _HomepageWidgetState#e0d4a
build: _SecondPageState#06d69
build: _SecondPageState#9c9f7
build: _SecondPageState#db373
build: _SecondPageState#4d4ca
build: _SecondPageState#15247
build: _SecondPageState#06d69
build: _SecondPageState#9c9f7
build: _SecondPageState#db373
build: _SecondPageState#4d4ca
build: _HomepageWidgetState#0d598
build: _HomepageWidgetState#3bb96
build: _HomepageWidgetState#09270
build: _HomepageWidgetState#640bb
build: _HomepageWidgetState#6385a
build: _HomepageWidgetState#ed720
build: _HomepageWidgetState#f45da
```

It seems a new State object is created every time I navigate between the two pages, and also its build() method keeps getting called, even if the Widget is not currently visible.

Obviously something is wrong (?) - what is going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Methods like `Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/');` usually create and "push" new widget. It could be the reason, why you have new state.

You can find example of Drawer in [Stocks app](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/examples/stocks/lib/stock_home.dart)

Comment: Yeah, a new Widget is fine .. but why does it keep the old references and continue to run build() on them?

Comment: Thanks, I marked this as correct as you pointed me in the right direction - looks there were two reasons: 1. Both widgets are sharing the same Drawer instance (so I think the Drawer is keeping the references live forever(?)) and 2. If you're currently on the page you're trying to navigate to you should just pop the drawer (to not get a 2nd reference). But I think the main issue here is the first one I mentioned.

Answer (score 4):

Flutter is creating a `State` object for each route you push, and calling its `build()` method every time you push a new route onto the navigator stack. You aren't currently providing a way to pop anything off the stack.

You should probably avoid specifying a drawer for `SecondPage`, and instead force the user to navigate back to the home page using the back button. This will prevent the `Navigator` history stack from becoming arbitrarily large.

Comment: Thanks Collin, that's the solution I ended up using; just having a main page with the Drawer and the rest with a back button. Your explanation makes sense. So I guess if I wanted to have multiple routes with a Drawer then I'd have to pop the current route if it has a drawer before navigating.